# Autowired JavaMailSender Object Throws Null Pointer Exception Except RestController Class

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, autowired

I am creating a simple rest service.
I have a rest controller class which has a post mapping endpoint "/insert" :

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/restapi")
    public class RestService{

        @PostMapping("/insert")
        public void insert(@RequestBody String body){
            DBClass db = new DBClass();
            db.insert(body);
        }

    }
```

I got a class called DBClass which connects to the database and inserts objects. But if it fails, it will send an email about the error. Here is the insert method:

```
public void insertToFirestore(String body) {

        try {
            //insertDB
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MailService ms = new MailService();
            ms.sendMail(to,subject,text);
        }

    }
```

And there is a MailService class where I do things about mails. It has a method called sendMail :

```
@Component
public class MailService {

    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender jms;

    public void sendMail(String to,String subject,String text) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);
        jms.send(message);
    }
}
```

I had done the configurations in the application.properties file. So if I try to send mail in the rest controller class it works just fine but when I try to send mail in MailService class Javamailsender object throws null pointer exception. I also tried sending mails other than Rest Controller class and they all threw the same exception.

@Autowired keyword initialize the java mail sender object only in Rest Controller class. What is the reason for that ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your `insertToFirestore` function inside spring bean class?

Comment: Paste the stack-trace. Also where is the `@Autowired` in the RestController?

Comment: No it has no annotations. Just a simple java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are instantiating the `DBClass` object with `new DBClass()` instead of creating a Spring bean and inject it in the `RestService`.
Therefore the `DBClass` instance is not managed by Spring and the `JavaMailSender` is `null`.

I would suggest to create a bean for `DBClass` and autowiring it in the `RestService`.

E.g:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/restapi")
public class RestService {

    @Autowired
    private DBClass db;

    @PostMapping("/insert")
    public void insert(@RequestBody String body){
        db.insert(body);
    }

}
```

Keep in mind that the `DBClass` needs to be **threadsafe** if you are creating a Spring bean for it with the default singleton scope.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I Autowired every variable to reach the MailService class: So DBClass and MailService objects are also autowired . Then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Auto-wiring will not work when class is initialized with `new` keyword. Here in your case you are initializing `MailService` with `new` keyword, that's why it will not autowire `JavaMailSender` inside it.

You can try below code which will work -

```
@Component
class DBClass {
    @Autowired
    private MailService ms;
    public void insertToFirestore(String body) {

        try {
            //insertDB
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ms.sendMail(to,subject,text);
        }

    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/restapi")
public class RestService{
@Autowired
private DBClass db;
    @PostMapping("/insert")
    public void insert(@RequestBody String body){
        db.insert(body);
    }

}
```

Comment: I needed to Autowired db object in rest controller class, then it worked. Thank you for your reply :)